How to select boundary edges based on fields in geometry nodes?
For example in the picture below I want to split the geometry at the white marked edges based on the colors of the voronoi.

I tried to compare the two faces next to each edge and split if there is any difference, but my setup does not work.
Setup:

Result:


Your setup is actually almost correct. However, you would have to compare the respective colors of the adjacent faces in order to be able to explicitly select certain edges.
Something like this:

Here I evaluate the colors of the two adjacent faces from the face domain and use the node Compare (setting its input type to Color) to compare the color values obtained.
(Blender 4.2.0+)

If you want to support two cells with the exact same color (no idea how likely is that to happen), you can do so if you compare cell positions instead of colors. There's also a "Face Group Boundaries" node, but I think it's less reliable in this case because converting color/position to integer is less reliable...

Thank you so much! This helps a lot!
